# Huis Clos Description of the room

Tags: french-language, jean-paul-sartre, no-exit

How does the room in hell in the first scene of the French play *Huis Clos* (*No Exit* in English) by Jean-Paul Sartre look like and how does Joseph Garcin react to it?

Comment: Perhaps you should read it and post an answer.

Comment: @mikado Great Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Room from the french Play "Huis Clos", "No Exit" in English by Jean-Paul Sartre represents Hell.

Everything in this room is Second Empire furniture, there is for example a Louis-Phillipe armchair. There is a bronze ornament on the mantelpiece. There are no mirrors, nor windows and nothing breakable. There is also no bathroom for hygiene, nor a bed to sleep.
There are more rooms, more passages, stairs and floors. The light is always turnes on and there is no light-switch.

Garcin questions the design and the available things in the room. He is confused, that he can't close his eyes as he is dead and that the Valet offers no teeth-brushes because in Hell people lose their sense of human dignity.